apply bold to some words with space in text in matplotlib
I want apply bold to some words with space in text in matplotlib
Example Code
I need to insert some text into a graph.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s.plot()

plt.text(1.2, 1.8, "Jame's Steward: math exam")
plt.text(1.0, 1.5, "Jame's roy Steward: math exam", weight='bold')

plt.show()


How do I bold only words before a colon (:)?
Here's the answer I found on stackoverflow.
Display some text as bold using matplotlib
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s.plot()

plt.text(1.2, 1.8, r"$\bf{Jame's Steward}$: math exam")
plt.text(1.0, 1.5, r"$\bf{Jame's roy Steward}$: math exam")

plt.show()


This method doesn't recognize the space, and the font seems to be subtly different from bold.
I'll tolerate a slightly different font, but please tell me how to recognize the space bar when only part of it is bold.

"Space" is a character; "space bar" is a key on the keyboard that generates that character when pressed.

You're using LaTeX's math mode ($...$), which will strip the spaces.
Instead use \textbf{} with usetex=True (see text):
plt.text(1.2, 1.8, r"\textbf{Jame's Steward}: math exam", usetex=True)
plt.text(1.0, 1.5, r"\textbf{Jame's roy Steward}: math exam", usetex=True)

Output:


I copied it over and ran it, and got the following error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex',  RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found  i run this code in google colab.(matplotlib 3.7.1, pandas 2.0.3)

@braggart you might need to have latex installed on your computer
